# Oracle: Need to commit after CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW

Tags: sql, oracle

Silly question, but I can't remember how this works.
Need to commit after a CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, DDL statements automatically commit in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Correct oracle will preform an implicit commit on any DDL statement, regardless of whether the statement succeeds or fails. You can also explicitly commit by using the `COMMIT` command and for more control use `SAVEPOINT` command to choose where to `ROLLBACK`.